# LPC1768 GPIO interrupt flags - are they set even if interrupt isn't enabled?

Tags: interrupt, gpio, lpc

On the LPC1768, should I expect the GPIO interrupt status register bits (in IO{0,2}IntStat{R,F}) to be set on rising/falling edges, even if the corresponding interrupt enable bit (in IO{0,2}IntEn{R,F}) has not been set?  That's how interrupt flags have worked on other microcontrollers I've worked with, but it doesn't seem to be working here, and I don't see this behavior defined one way or the other in the LPC176x user manual.

My use case for this is to verify that an external pulsing signal is continuously present.  I have no need to be informed of each edge that occurs, I just want to periodically check a flag to see if an edge has been detected since the last check.

Answer (score 0):

Further experiments have shown that the rising/falling edge status bits will NEVER be set for a pin that doesn't have the corresponding interrupt enable bit set.  However, I was able to accomplish my goals anyway (edge detection without any actual interrupts being generated) by enabling interrupts for the GPIO pins of interest, but not enabling the NVIC interrupt channel that all the GPIO interrupts are funneled through - EINT3, on this particular chip.